# Multiple remote sessions on Mac OS

Tags: mac, remote-desktop

In Windows there is RDP. You cannot use RDP like VNC to see what is going on a screen, it is designed to start a session in a PC and work on it.

In Windows Server you can have multiple sessions simultaneously, so multiple users can work on the server.

My question is: how can I accomplish that on Mac? How can I have an iMac and let two users connect to it simultaneously to different sessions?

Comment: Will the users be using the same or different user accounts?

Comment: It really doesn't matter. But users should see different desktops with different things, like in Windows

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/8966/mac-os-x-multi-user-thin-client-server-terminal-server See the Aqua Connect and iRAPP.

Answer (score 2):

If you have OSX 10.7 installed, there is a [new feature in *screen sharing*](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4715) to allow this.  You can now log into an existing session that's open on the computer, [or another session in the background, running in parallel](http://www.macworld.com/article/161220/2011/07/lion_airdop_screen_sharing.html).  It's similar to what Terminal Server provides (when used with multiple accounts), only free.

Comment: About the client.. Is only available for Mac? Can a user get connecte form  a pc sometime?